# Error in manual derivative calculation

Tags: derivatives

I need to compute the derivate of

$g(x) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{x \sqrt{x+1}}\right)$

Simplifying this I get

$g(x) = \ln(1) - (\ln x + \frac{1}{2}\ln(x+1))$

Evaluating the derivate I get

$g'(x) = 0-(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x+2})$

I have compared my result to WolframAlphas answer and while my denominator is the same my numerator is different.
My result is $-3x+2$
WA result is $-x+2$.

I assume my mistake is in the multiplication of the negative sign, but why is this wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Looks OK. Presumably you fed the simplifed version of $g(x)$ into Wolfram Alpha, **without parentheses**.  Wrong input, wrong output.

Comment: I input the following into WA. "derivative of ln(1/x*sqrt(x+1))" And so yes, it seems I input the wrong equation into WA. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha says the same thing. Take a common denominator and check for yourself, your derivative is fine.
I just checked and got -(3x+2) from WA.

Comment: I see. My error was that i forgot the additional parenthesis when inputting the equation in WA.